# Entity Framework referential integrity not being enforced

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

Using EF6, I have two tables in an SQL database and I've used database first to create the EF diagram from the database.

My database is missing a foreign key constraint between the PK of one table and a foreign key in the other.

Rather than add the foreign key constraint into the database I created it as an association in the EF model.

The association looks good in the EF model, it has the correct principal and dependant.

However if I delete a row from the principal table when dependants are present, referential integrity doesn't kick in and the principal row gets deleted.

I know I can just add the relationship into the SQL database and update model from database. But I'd like to understand the scope of functionality of EF and whether it should be possible to add a relationship in the EF model but not in the SQL database and for it to still work?

It seems to me that if the association (relationship) exists in EF but not in MSSQL, then the association is ignored for referential integrity when you delete a row via EF?

Comment: functionality which you want is already there with EF, you just want to use it correctly,If you want to delete parent and enforce that all its depedent are also deleted you need to set cascade delete to true. look into your migration file what it is set to.Also while deleting parent you might also need to load all its child.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking for cascaded deletes, I want a referential integrity exception to be thrown when I try to delete a principal row that has related dependency rows present. As I said in the question, I can add the relationship into the database schema, but I want to understand what EF does with associations with respect to referential integrity. It seems that EF lets you create an association that does nothing with respect to referential integrity if there isn;t a corresponding relationship in the db schema?

Answer (score 0):

> However if I delete a row from the principal table when dependents are present, referential integrity doesn't kick in and the principal row gets deleted.

Dependents are present in database, or are present in Context?

If you haven't loaded all the dependent entities in the context, there is no way for EF to delete them. It needs their key for the delete statement. It doesn't even know they exist if they are not in the context.

So, the only way for referential integrity to work would be if EF retrieves all related entities into the context, on delete of principal entity, so it could issue a delete statement for every one of them (even if there are thousands).

I think, though, if there are dependent entities present in context, EF will issue delete statement anyway (even if it expects db to do all the work).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Dependents are present in the database, I don't load the dependants into the context because it I'm using an OData client and don't want to bring additional data over the wire. I'm only looking into why referential integrity doesn't kick in (I don't want cascaded deletes, I want a referential integrity exception when I try to delete a principal row that has dependent rows present). From what you're saying it sounds as though an association created in EF will not inherently enforce referential integrity if the underlying database scheme does not also have the same relationship in it.

Comment: No, it will only enforce referential integrity of the loaded entities, nothing else.